# I want to add marker on my map using the latitude and longitude that i retrieve from my database

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Does any one know what is the problem on my code? I want to add markers on my map using the latitude and longitude that i retrieved from my database. **But no marker appeared**. I am sure that I am receiveing the location from my database but I don't know why the marker did'nt appear

```java
public class PassengerMainscreen_Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    boolean isPermissionGranted;
    TextView textView;
    DatabaseReference firebaseDatabase;
    GoogleMap googleMap;
    Marker marker;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_passenger_mainscreen);

        checkpermission();
        textView = findViewById(R.id.LocEmpty);

        //CHECKING GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES
        if (isPermissionGranted) {
            if (checkGooglePlayServices()) {
                SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.CONTAINER, supportMapFragment).commit();
                supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services Not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkGooglePlayServices() {
        GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int result = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (result == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            return true;
        } else if (googleApiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(result)) {
            Dialog dialog = googleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, result, 201, new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    Toast.makeText(PassengerMainscreen_Activity.this, "User Cancelled Dialog", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void checkpermission() {
        Dexter.withContext(this).withPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION).withListener(new PermissionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {
                isPermissionGranted = true;
                Toast.makeText(PassengerMainscreen_Activity.this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), "");
                intent.setData(uri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
            }
        }).check(); //PERMISSION END
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
        this.googleMap = googleMap;


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

      getbusLocation();
      
    }

    private void getbusLocation() {

        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Location");
        firebaseDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                Double lat = Double.valueOf(snapshot.child("latitude").getValue().toString());
                Double lng = Double.valueOf(snapshot.child("longitude").getValue().toString());
                textView.setText(lat + "," + lng);

                // DISPLAYING MARKER ON THE MAP
                LatLng loc = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.position(loc);
                marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line of code where you are getting null pointer exception `googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc).title("bus"));` is because you have just declared variable `googleMap` but not initialised so you can initialise `googleMap` variable in  `onMapReady` method as you are getting in parameter

Like this

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {

    this.googleMap = googleMap;    

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    
    // use googleMap variable after this only
}
```

but make sure you use `googleMap` variable only after it's initialisation so you have to move code of firebase into seperate function and call it after initialisation of `googleMap`

Comment: Hello sir thank you it worked. The error is gone but I don't know why there's no marker appeared on my map.

Comment: Can you please add your updated code and i hope you have firebase code after googleMap variable initialised

Comment: Hello Sir. I have updated my code above, hope you can find the problem on my code Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure ? have you tried to check by scrolling on map . becuase you have not added code to move focus to marker .. can you add this line before addMarker ```googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));```